# ArrayOfXElement to DataSet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, xsd

No, there is no appropriate answer in stack overflow yet. I am getting ArrayOfXElement in .net Core through Connected Services. But, I need to convert it into DataSet. How can I do that? I wrote the following code using all the examples I had, but I think I am playing with wrong nodes/elements. I do see schema as well as data in the nodes.

```
public static DataSet ToDataSet(this ArrayOfXElement xElementsForSchool)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    foreach (XElement xElement in xElementsForSchool.Nodes)
    {
        string xml = xElement.ToString();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.ReadXml(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
        dataSet.Tables.Add(table);
    }

    return dataSet;
}
```

ArrayOfXElement consists of two Node elements. Contest on the first Node is as below

```
<xs:schema id="Results" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Results" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="School">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" msdata:DataType="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
       </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Content of 2nd Node is as below.

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
      <Results xmlns="">
        <School diffgr:id="School1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
          <ID>83d08e0a-411d-4546-9d7f-0002ee22a3f3</ID>
          <Name>Canoga Park</Name>
        </School>
      </Results>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of your xElements and expected data that as a result must be contained in the dataset?

Comment: It has two nodes. First is like below
`<xs:schema id="Results" >
  <xs:element name="Results" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="School">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" msdata:DataType="System.Guid, mscorlib type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />            
         </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>`

Comment: 2nd node is like:
`<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <Results xmlns="">
    <School diffgr:id="School1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <ID>83d08e0a-433d-4546-9d7f-1112ee22a3f3</ID>
      <Name>New York</Name>
</School>
</Results>
</diffgr:diffgram>`

Comment: Expectation is to get one DataSet, which has one table named School. having columns ID and  Name, and having values ID = 83d08e0a-433d-4546-9d7f-1112ee22a3f3 and Name = New York - Thanks  @IliarTurdushev

Comment: The first node is XML schema, and the second node is XML data. Does `xElementsForSchool` always contain two nodes, where first node is schema, and second node is data?

Comment: ArrayOfXElement object is a list of 2 Nodes objects. Both Nodes have different structure as shown above. The first node starts with `<xs:schema id="Results" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">` & ends with  `</xs:schema>`. The 2nd node starts with `<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">` and has columns of School element with their values under School Element. It ends with  `</School></Results></diffgr:diffgram>` we need dataset from it.

Comment: I have updated the details in the question with easy formatting.

Comment: What is your ArrayOfXElement?

Answer (score 8):

Use this function

```
public DataSet ToDataSet(ArrayOfXElement arrayOfXElement)
{
    var strSchema = arrayOfXElement.Nodes[0].ToString();
    var strData = arrayOfXElement.Nodes[1].ToString();
    var strXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n\t<DataSet>";
    strXml += strSchema + strData;
    strXml += "</DataSet>";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("TestDataSet");
    ds.ReadXml(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXml)));

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: You can use string interpolation for improved readability and performance: `var strXml = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n\t<DataSet>{strSchema}{strData}</DataSet>";`